# Microsoft SQL fails Sqoop import

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I want to fetch databases to see that is set up but i got this errors. I tried different methods for firewall but it's keep saying

> ```
> 16/01/07 01:18:21 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.x.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error:
> ```
>
> "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that
>   an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
>   are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2293)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:506)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1523)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1040)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:554)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1019)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>       16/01/07 01:18:22 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host xx.x.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed
>   out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of
>   SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at
>   the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
>   by a firewall.".
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host xx.x.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed
>   out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of
>   SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at
>   the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
>   by a firewall.".
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:73)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>       Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.x.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed.
>   Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure
>   that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the
>   port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2293)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:506)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1523)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1040)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:554)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1019)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
>       ... 7 more
>
> ```
> Note : Port 1433 it's up .
> ```

Comment: Could you post your SQOOP command?

Comment: Is the machine running sqoop able to ping/connect to the sql server machine normally?

Comment: @vmachan sqoop list-databases --connect jdblc:sqlserver://<ip>:1433 --username <user> --password <pass>

Comment: @cricket_007 ping got my machine frozen

Comment: @cricket_007 now works but no response back . I am sure that i use the corect ip and sql is running but no response back

Comment: If ping does not give you proper response then you will not be able to connect via SQL / JDBC and SQOOP either..

Comment: Have you checked the configuration on MS SQL Server? Is TCP/IP enabled?